# Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, string, eval, timespan

' >
    
    
 System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'String' is not valid
 
 
    ' >
    
    
I have a gridview , i want that the column"duréeCalculée" take like this value "text='<%# (TimeSpan.Parse(Eval("heure_retour") - Eval("heure_depart"))).ToString()%>'"
but when my page generate I got this problem(Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'String' is not valid)
Can U help Me?

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: yes, It's my first question in this website! my question is how to successfully make the conversion of a timespan to String .

Comment: Then you should read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then come back and edit your question.

Comment: That's not how this site works. Write a good question and you're more likely to get help. Currently your question has a horrible title and nothing but code and an error for content. Did you read those pages? I notice you've added an answer below that looks like it should really have been added to the question. You do know that you can *edit* the question?

Comment: ok Biffen ; I appreciate your help .

Comment: In my codebehind i have this lines: <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="duree_reelle" runat="server" text='<%# (TimeSpan.Parse(Eval("heure_retour") - Eval("heure_depart"))).ToString()%>' >
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate> and when I generate my page I got this problem :System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'String' is not valid !

Comment: Please, please, *please* **edit** your question to include all relevant information. *Don't* put it in an answer, *don't* put it in a comment, *do* put it *in the question itself*.

Comment: "my question is urgent!" is the fastest way to get ignored and downvoted

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain with this little information that anyone will be able to help you. It would seem that `TimeSpan.Spare()`  is returning a structure of type `TimeSpan`. When you try to use `.ToString()`, your compiler isn't figuring out what to do because `.ToString()` isn't recognised as a conversion method for types `TimeSpan`.

Most likely what you need to do is get the element `TimeSpan` that you want and then parse it. Something along the lines of

```
double Element1 = TimeSpan.Element1;
char str[64];
sprintf(str,"%f",Element1);
```

Where `Element1` is the name of the element you wish to retrieve.